# What's the difference between the two Animus Hack kill streaks?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

So there's two kill streaks, the **Animus Hack** and the **Silent Animus Hack**.

> #### Animus Hack:
>
> When the STREAK counter reaches **9**, the ANIMUS HACK enables you to kill whomever you want from a distance.
>
> You earn +100 points when you kill a non-TARGET Templar.
> *(80 Abstergo Credits)*

> #### Silent Animus Hack:
>
> When the STREAK counter reaches **7**, the ANIMUS HACK enables you to kill whomever you want from a distance.
>
> You earn +100 points when you kill a non-TARGET Templar.
> *(80 Abstergo Credits)*

As you can see, the descriptions are practically identical except one is for 9 kills, the other, 7.

**What's the difference between the two Animus Hack streaks?**

I would have thought the **Silent Animus Hack** would have been more useful and easier to acquire since it requires less kills and the potential to be *silent*.  I'm guessing it only counts **Silent** or **Incognito** kills and **Stuns** for the streak?  The regular **Animus Hack** is more elusive and *not* silent.  I'm guessing it probably counts *any* kill/stun?  Both cost the same.

Videos I've seen on the non-beta release just demonstrate its use for the most part but I couldn't tell the difference in any of them.  I've only seen two guys online to be able to use it (with one actually killing me) but don't know what to think of it.  Can anyone clear this up?

Comment: I'm guessing you're correct in your assumptions, but I'm not sure/don't have proof.

Comment: I'm also guessing you're right, but I am too terrible at multiplayer to ever get a streak bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that despite having essentially the same exact description, the **Silent Animus Hack** only counts **Silent** kills and **Stuns**.

Aww, I was hoping there would have been some more ninja-like abilities in the game... oh well.